# Can't seem to move labels manually in QGIS, 1.80

Tags: qgis, labeling

Trying to move labels manually in QGIS.  I am having the same problem when adding x,y to the attribute table.  I picked (Type Decimal Number (real)), it's the only one out of the 3 choices that has 'double'.  After enabling the Edit tool, the 'Move' and 'Rotation' tools remained greyed out. (1.80 Lisbo, using PC)  Help?

Comment: did you asign the newly created attributes to the data-defined label properties (i think in advanced tab)

Answer (score 1):

Hey this is an old question. I don't really know the entire answer but how I have got around the problem of moving labels is by utilising the Pluggin "EasyCustomLabeling".  This will allow you to move labels and to add arrows to the labels.

As for the xy.  I gennerally added the points in edit mode.  Use the "Numerical Vertex Edit" (another pluggin) tool to manually input the xy coords.

I hope this helps.